# How to make old-fashioned input layers used only for test phase?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

For some reasons, I have to use old fashioned "*.prototxt" file format, so at the beginning of my prototxt, I have to write something like this:

```
layer {
    name: 'input-data'
    type: 'Python'
    top: 'data'
    top: 'gt_boxes'
    python_param {
        module: 'roi_data_layer.layer'
        layer: 'RoIDataLayer'
        param_str: "'num_classes': 2"
    }
    include {
        phase: TRAIN
    }
}
input: "data"
input_shape {
    dim: 1
    dim: 3
    dim: 224
    dim: 224
}
```

Now I'd like to make the input layer only avaiable for TEST phase, otherwise a "caffe Top blob 'data' produced by multiple sources" will be raised.

I cannot set "input_param" attribute to the layer, since I have to work on a outdated forked version of Caffe. So how could it do that? Or is there any way that can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
layer {
    name: 'input-test'
    type: 'Input'
    top: 'data'
    top: 'gt_boxes'

    include {
        phase: TEST
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the shape specification though